# Glow behind reflective text

Tags: materials, compositing-nodes, lighting

I have a reflective ( Mirror Surfaced ) text on a dark background / Wall so it's barely visible. Backlighting does not light up the scene too much, the text is reflective and would only pickup the backlight on the wall. What I needed is to make glow effect behind the reflective text.

How could i achieve this effect?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and node settings.

Comment: The best way to do such an effect is to make sure your dark background is not totally 100% black. What I would do is to start with a mid tone gray RGB (128,128,128) and apply a emission material on the rear side of the 3d text. Adjust the lighting and the gray material until it satisfy the style I am looking for. Will try to create a file to show case it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have attached a scene for your reference.

[image]

Basically, the scene is straightforward.
A text "G" with reflective and emission material & a wall with white material. **Make sure you turn off ambient occlusion in your World Tab** as it will throw false lighting in the scene. The wall material is almost completely white, due to the lack of light in the rest of the scene only the backlight is visible.

[image]

Hope this helps and is what you are looking for.

Comment: This may be an average answer to a bad question, but it looks awesome. ♥

Comment: Yeah the problem is that people sweep these sort of questions away too quickly, sometimes new users don't even know how to ask the right questions ... it takes patience to understand these sorts and it can help countless others who are just starting out. I hope the commmunity is less critical and more compassionate.